# ASCII Characters Messed Up in simple C Program

Tags: c, cryptography, cs50, caesar-cipher

I have written this simple program for an assignment, but when I input my text, the output gives me symbols instead of chars.  any help would be appreciated.  I do not know why my output appears that way, but the program seems to compile fine.  Maybe it is working and I need to just do a base test with the math to see if it is functioning properly.  In any event if anyone sees errors in this, feedback is much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

string Crypto(string, int); // rotation


int main(int argc, string argv[])
   {
    int k = 0;
    // error checing
    if (argc == 0 || argc == 1 || argc > 2)
   {
        // get mad
        printf("Enter 1 integer as an argument.  Stop messing around!\n Try Again: ");
        return 1;
   }
    else
   {
        //create command line arguments to be stored into k
        k = atoi(argv[1]);
        k = k * 1;
   }

    // Get text to be encrypted
    printf("Enter the text you want to encrypt: \n");
    string a = GetString();

    string b = Crypto(a, k);
    printf("%s\n", b);

    return 0;
 }

 //Now let's get cryptic
 string
 Crypto(string a, int k)
 {
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(a); i < n; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] >= 65 && a[i] <= 90)
        {
            c = ((26 - (91 - a[i] + k) % 26));
            a[i] = c + 'A';
        }
        else
        {
            c = ((26 - (123 - a[i] + k % 26)));
            a[i] = c + 'a';
        }
     }
     return a;
  }
```

Comment: Pranav got me on the right path.  The line I needed was       a[strlen(a)+ i + 1] = '\0';

Comment: Observation: `argc` is only correct if it is 2, which most simply and accurately written as `if (argc != 2)` (rather than `if (argc == 0 || argc == 1 || argc > 2)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function `Crypto`, you need to attach a `\0` (null) character to signify the end of the string. Just before `return a;`, write a `a[i+1] = '\0';` statement.